# Pandas dataframe take raises indices out-of-bounds

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, chunks

I am using [pandas.DataFrame.take](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.take.html) to keep only certain rows of a dataframe (the ones which value in one column matches a certain regex pattern).

In order to do so, I am building a list of the indices to keep in a loop checking that each row matches the pattern:

```
for index, row in combined_csv.iterrows():
     if re.match(regex_files_to_keep, row['commit_file']):
          indices_to_keep.append(index)
```

The index value is thus returned by [pandas.DataFrame.iterrows](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html).

My dataset is stored as a CSV file. It is too big to be read in one time, I am using the chunksize argument of [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html).

The `take` applied to the first chunk works without any problem. However, from the second chunk on, it raises the following error:

> IndexError: indices are out-of-bounds

I printed the list values and the indices of the first and last element of the data frame (using `combined_csv.index[0]` and `combined_csv.index[-1]`). All the values in the `indices_to_keep` list are within the boundaries defined by the indices of the first and last element of the data frame.

Why am I getting this error then ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was that the [pandas.DataFrame.take](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.take.html) method takes as argument the **position** of the row to remove in the current dataframe, and not its **index**. The confusion comes from the argument name which is *indices*, but the documentation explicitly states:

> An array of ints indicating which positions to take

Let me explain the difference with an example.

Say you have a chunksize of 40000. The first **index** of your data frame built from your second chunk will then be 40000. However, the **position** of this row is 0, and that's the position value that `take` is expecting.

That's why you need to substract the number of rows you already went through (chunksize * (chunk_number - 1)) from your **indices**. My corresponding line of code is :

```
indices_to_keep = [x - (chunk_size * (chunk_number - 1)) for x in indices_to_keep]
```

Now you have a list of the **positions** of the rows to keep, and you can use the take as expected.

Please let me know if the vocabulary (position and index) is not appropriate so that I can correct it. I am not a native English speaker and the meaning of these words is very important in this problem.